# Scala: Nil vs List()

Tags: scala

In Scala, is there any difference at all between `Nil` and `List()`?

If not, which one is more idiomatic Scala style? Both for creating new empty lists and pattern matching on empty lists.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

```
scala> println (Nil == List())
true

scala> println (Nil eq List())
true

scala> println (Nil equals List())
true

scala> System.identityHashCode(Nil)
374527572

scala> System.identityHashCode(List())
374527572
```

Nil is more idiomatic and can be preferred in most cases.
Questions?

Comment: You could mention that `Nil` is more idiomatic.

Comment: Do they both create a new object every time? Does that matter?

Comment: Added System.identityHashCode to clarify what "eq" already says - they're the same object.

Comment: @James - Thank you. Guess I should have investigated what the `eq` method did.

Comment: @Bart: Maybe, if no Nil object was used before. But every list needs a Nil as a terminator, so I suspect, almost always one has been created before, or will later be needed anyway. And since it is an object, you just need one in the whole JVM, which is shared between all references.

Comment: Besides, Nil references an object directly, whereas List() is a method call.

Comment: But `Nil` can't have a type, right? `scala> val a = Nil(String)
<console>:7: error: object String is not a value
       val a = Nil(String)`

Comment: What kind of syntax is that: `a: List[String] = List()`? You may write `val a : List[String] = Nil` and Nil is of type Nothing, which is a special beast, because it extends everything (which no class/type else does), so `val b : List[Int] = Nil` looks as if it was of different type, but `a == b` yields true. Both are of type Nothing.

Comment: Isn't `List[A]()` (not `Nil`) necessary as an accumulator value for foldLeft? Example - `scala> Map(1 -> "hello", 2 -> "world").foldLeft(List[String]())( (acc, el) => acc :+ el._2)
res1: List[String] = List(hello, world)` Using `Nil` as the accumulator here wouldn't work.

Comment: `Map(1 -> "hello", 2 -> "world").foldLeft(Nil: List[String])( _ :+ _._2)`

Comment: I have `Nil` questions after reading this - let me put them in the `List()`

Answer (score 89):

[User unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312172/user-unknown) has shown that the run time value of both `Nil` and `List()` are the same. However, their static type is not:

```
scala> val x = List()
x: List[Nothing] = List()

scala> val y = Nil
y: scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type = List()

scala> def cmpTypes[A, B](a: A, b: B)(implicit ev: A =:= B = null) = if (ev eq null) false else true
cmpTypes: [A, B](a: A, b: B)(implicit ev: =:=[A,B])Boolean

scala> cmpTypes(x, y)
res0: Boolean = false

scala> cmpTypes(x, x)
res1: Boolean = true

scala> cmpTypes(y, y)
res2: Boolean = true
```

This is of particular importance when it is used to infer a type, such as in a fold's accumulator:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(List[Int]())((x, y) => y :: x)
res6: List[Int] = List(3, 2, 1)

scala> List(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(Nil)((x, y) => y :: x)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int]
 required: scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type
       List(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(Nil)((x, y) => y :: x)
                                               ^
```

Comment: i do not understand why 2::Nil works but not fold's accumulator y::x

Comment: @FUD Well, `y :: x` *does* work. The problem is that the type it returns is not the type expected. It returns `List[Int]`, while the type expected is either `List[Nothing]` or `Nil.type` (I think the former, but maybe the latter).

Answer (score 29):

As user unknown's answer shows, they are the same object.

Idiomatically Nil should be preferred because it is nice and short. There's an exception though: if an explicit type is needed for whatever reason I think

```
List[Foo]()
```

is nicer than

```
Nil : List[Foo]
```

Comment: There's also `List.empty[Foo]` as a third alternative.