# Why do I see List() in the trace of recursive function, whereas I only use Nil?

Tags: scala, recursion

This function & function call :

```
  def listRange(lo: Int, hi: Int): List[Int] =
    if (lo >= hi) Nil
    else {
        println(listRange(lo + 1, hi) + ","+lo)
        lo :: listRange(lo + 1, hi)
    }                                            
  listRange(1, 3)
```

produces this output :

```
/> List(),2
//| List(2),1
//| List(),2
//| res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

Why is an empty list being output with every recursive iteration ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
List()
```

[is equivalent to `Nil`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981850/scala-nil-vs-list), and so the final call to

```
println(listRange(lo + 1, hi) + ","+lo)
```

will get a value of `Nil` from `listRange`, and display that.

Comment: `Nil.toString` //res6: String = List()

Comment: @Brian Agnew why is a value of Nil returned for each recursive call since the List is initially populated ?

Comment: It isn't `val nilList: List[Int] = Nil` is printed as `List()`. And since you are printing the result of the next recursive step in each call, you will end up printing exactly that at the end of the recursion. [This running example](http://ideone.com/nJwoft) should help you understand what is happening.