# Using Nil as Initial Accumulator in Tail Recursive Function

Tags: scala, null, accumulator

[Mr. Daniel Sobral](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53013/daniel-c-sobral) answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5986220/409976) that `Nil` can't be used as an initial accumulator to a `fold`.

Doesn't work with `Nil` as initial accumulator value

```
scala> xs
res9: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> xs.foldLeft(Nil)( (acc, elem) => elem.toString :: acc)
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[String]
 required: scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type
              xs.foldLeft(Nil)( (acc, elem) => elem.toString :: acc)
```

But it will work if I pass `List[String]()`.

```
scala> xs.foldLeft(List[String]())( (acc, elem) => elem.toString :: acc)
res7: List[String] = List(3, 2, 1)
```

Yet why can I use `Nil` in the following tail recursive function?

```
scala>       def toStringList(as: List[Int]): List[String] = {
     |         def go(bs: List[Int], acc: List[String]): List[String]= bs match {
     |           case Nil => acc
     |           case x :: xs => go(xs, x.toString :: acc)
     |         }
     |        println(as)
     |        go(as, Nil)   
     |       }
toStringList: (as: List[Int])List[String]
```

Comment: `Nil` (per se) is an (empty) `List[Nothing]` where as `List[String]()` or `List.empty[String]` are empty lists (obviously) of element type `String`.

Comment: Ah, @RandallSchulz- `Because lists are covariant in Scala, this makes scala.collection.immutable.Nil an instance of List[T], for any element of type T.` -http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Nothing. Thank you.

Comment: The signature for `foldLeft` is `def foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B` and method signatures don't have variance. If you start with `Nothing`, that's all you can ever have. And there are no `Nothing`!

Comment: if you want to accumulate with `Nil` in folds, just add type ascription: xs.foldRight(Nil: List[String])(_ :: _).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Scala starts type inference with the first parameter list. So given `def foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B` and

```
xs.foldLeft(Nil)(...)
```

it infers `B` as `Nil.type` (type which has only one value: `Nil`) and uses this to type-check the second parameter list, which obviously fails. However, `List[String]()` has the type `List[String]` and so `B` is `List[String]`, which will work with your `f`. Another workaround is to write the type parameter explicitly:

```
xs.foldLeft[List[String]](Nil)(...)
```

In the second program, type of `acc` is given (and has to be, since it's a function argument), so no type inference happens corresponding to your initial problem.