# In Scala, is there any _performance_ difference between List() and Nil?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a function that accepts a object and a list:

```
case class Point(x: Int, y: Int)
def f1(w: Point, l: List[String]) =  { /* do something /* }
```

I would typically use it like this:

```
val w = Point(1,1)
val lst = List("Hello", "world")
f1(w, lst) // non empty list
```

Many times I would need to call the function with empty list as second parameter:

```
f1(w, List()) // empty list
f1(w, Nil) // empty list
```

Is there any performance difference between the last two lines ?

I think using `List()` will invoke `List.apply()` method. Does Scala compiler optimize it to `Nil`?

#### EDIT1

This is not a duplicate of [Scala: Nil vs List()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981850/scala-nil-vs-list)

NOTE: Is there any performance difference between `Nil` vs `List()` ? Does Scala compiler do any optimizations here?

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti  Please check **EDIT1**.

Comment: Measure, don't speculate. Performance in not only about `scalac`, but also about the optimisations performed by the JVM.

Comment: @rightføld: Agreed. However, I want to know whether `List()` will eventually get converted to a `Nil` or something very similar at compile time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a class like this

```
import collections.immutable.List

class Test {
  val l = List() // or Nil
}
```

Compiling both of them and then checking the generated bytecode with `javap -v`

`List()` gives:

```
5: getstatic     #26                 // Field scala/collection/immutable/Nil$.MODULE$:Lscala/collection/immutable/Nil$;
8: putfield      #14                 // Field l:Lscala/collection/immutable/List;
```

And `Nil` gives:

```
5: getstatic     #24                 // Field scala/collection/immutable/Nil$.MODULE$:Lscala/collection/immutable/Nil$;
8: putfield      #13                 // Field l:Lscala/collection/immutable/Nil$;
```

So, the bytecode (and the performance) is the same for both. There might be other reasons to chose one over the other though, as described in the issue linked by Govind in the comments.

**A deeper dive into the rabbit hole**:

Looking at the sources List() is the sugar for List.apply() which is implemented like this:

```
def apply[A](xs: A*) = xs.toList
```

`toList` comes from `TraversableOnce` and calls `to[List]` which implicitly takes a `CanBuildFrom[Nothing, A, List[A]]`, which in this case will be `List.canBuildFrom`, which in turn comes from `ReusableCBF`, that builder will then be called with `.apply()`, `++= the empty array`, and then `build()`

How this can be eliminated/transformed into a `getstatic` for `List()` isn't very clear to me. (Or i missed something clever on the way).

Comment: The answer 'http://stackoverflow.com/a/5981960/508064' show that the 'System.identityHashCode` of both are the same which mean they are the same object.

Comment: And that is exactly what post says? a getstatic with the same value from Nil$.MODULE$, not sure what your comment adds.