# Is this pattern match redundant?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I recently fell over a scala pattern match, that looked more or less like this:

```
def func (li :List[Int]): List[Int] = li match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case start :+ tail => start
  case List() => li
}
```

Now, what these three different cases return is not so much what I am in interesed about.

I wondering whether a pattern match like this would ever have any effect? Is there any case at all, where third case could ever reached?

My initial thought is no, since all lists with more than 0 elements will always match on the first case, and therefore the second case could never be reached

Comment: Two or three cases? Anyways yeah the third case is redundant, it is the same as the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third case *is* redundant, because as far as I know, an empty list can only ever be `Nil`. `List` is sealed, so there won't be classes other than `::` and the object `Nil` extending it.

However, a list with more than 0 elements will always match on the *second* case. A list with no elements would match the first case (and the third case, if the first were not present).

Answer (score 2):

You can read the post: [Scala: Nil vs List()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5981850/2359227). From the point of view of pattern matching, they are the same. The third case will never hit.

In Scala source code you can find that [`case object Nil extends List[Nothing]`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L628), and that [empty list is Nil](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L655).